# Domain of sender address does not resolve (in reply to MAIL FROM command)

Tags: domain-name-system, email, postfix, email-server, email-bounces

When sending out emails with postfix I sometimes get this error:

```
451 #4.1.8 Domain of sender address <user@mydomain.tld> does not resolve 
(in reply to MAIL FROM command)
```

The domain `mydomain.tld` is resolvable though, meaning A, MX, PTR records are set properly.

However, the sending server does have a different domain `anotherdomain.tld` but it is allowed to send emails from `mydomain.tld` since I set the MX records of `mydomain.tld` to `anotherdomain.tld`. The envelope from of the problematic emails is `user@mydomain.tld`.

**Is there some other dns entry I have to set?**

**Or how else could I solve the problem?** (I would like to keep the server structure though)

Comment: As womble says, it's very hard for us to offer any real information while you redact the domain in question.  DNS is a public resource; I urge you, and authors of similar questions, **not** to redact domains in such questions.

Comment: @MadHatter: You are right. However I may not publish the domain name here unfortunately...

Comment: Whoever says that is foolish.  You'll have this problem until you fix it, and being open about the domain name is likely to get the problem fixed more quickly.  So ask whoever says that whether they prefer to be a little embarrassed but have working email, or save face but have non-working email.  Though I'm not even sure why they'd be embarrassed; we all have stuff break all the time, you're not the only ones!

Comment: Check to see if your domain has expired. Was the case for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply one of DNS resolution.  Either the receiving MTA doesn't have reliable DNS resolution, or your DNS servers are flaky.  Without knowing what domain `mydomain.tld` actually is, it's impossible for anyone to determine whether the latter is the case, but the more recipient domains who are sending you this error, the less likely the former becomes.

Comment: so you think the problem isn't that `anotherdomain.tld` is sending with the envelope from `user@mydomain.tld` but that `anotherdomain.tld` does actually not resolve? which dns entry does that error msg actually mean - is it the `A RECORD`? If it would be the `A` record of `mydomain.tld`, it would obviously not point to the IP of `anotherdomain.tld` - maybe that's the problem?

Comment: In short: No.  ANY.  No.

Comment: @adaptr: What does Postfix's resolver have to do with this problem?  It's an error from the recipient MTA.

Comment: I re-read it and deleted it, sorry.

Comment: I was able to fix it by changing the DNS entries for the `MX record`. I debugged using the `dig` command. It returned `;; Truncated, retrying in TCP mode` instead of a valid answer. Now everything is fine